# Python: How to sum up the values of a dictionary list in a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
timestamp                                asks
2022-01-01 00:00:00                 [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'12311'},{'price':'0.991', 'size':'20013'}]
2022-01-01 01:00:00                 [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'3122'},{'price':'0.991', 'size':'43221'}]
...
```

What I want to do is sum up the values of `size` for each`timestamp` to get the following DataFrame:

```
timestamp                 asks
2022-01-01 00:00:00       32324
2022-01-01 01:00:00       46343
...
```

i.e. `12311+20013= 32324`.

How can this be done (using pandas ideally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["asks"] = df["asks"].explode().str["size"].astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

- get each dictionary on a separate row
- get the "size" key's value for each of them

  - due to ducktyping, `.str[...]` works on anything that supports `__getitem__` which a dictionary does
- convert to integers and unexplode

to get

```py
>>> df

             timestamp   asks
0  2022-01-01 00:00:00  32324
1  2022-01-01 01:00:00  46343
```